# Small-step semantics: for-loops

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages, semantics, operational-semantics, small-step-semantics

I'm trying to construct the small-step semantic rules involving the for-loops, but I can't find anything about it in the literature (only about while-loops).

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this? This is a first attempt, where $s$ represents a statement and $e$ an expression:

$\quad \displaystyle\sigma, \text{for } s_1 \, e_1 \, e_2 \, s_2 \, \rightarrow \, \sigma, \text{if } e_1 \text{ then (} s_2 ; \, e_2; \, \text{for } s_1 \, e_1 \, e_2 \, s_2 \text{ ) else } skip$

Where $\sigma$ is a local value store, $s_1$ is for example $i = 0$, $e_1$ could equal $i < 4$ and $e_2$ $i=i+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attempt does not work. Note that $s_1$ is never executed. (And if you prepend the right-hand side with "$s_1;$", it will be executed multiple times.)

What you can do is to translate the for loop into an equivalent while loop:

$$\sigma,\text{for } s_1, e_1, e_2, s_2 \text{ endfor} \to \sigma, s_1; \text{while } e_1 \text{ do } s_2; e_2 \text{ endwhile}.$$